# Overload operator new[] for parametrized constructor

Tags: c++

Why `Person* p3 = new Person[5](7)` this is failing in the below code? How to use `operator new[]` for parametrized constructor? What to do if one want to invoke parametrized constructor with `new[]`?

```
class Person
{
    public:

    int age; 

    Person(){}

    Person(int age):age(age){}

    void* operator new(size_t size) throw(bad_alloc)
    {
        cout<<"In overloaded new"<<endl;
        return (::operator new(size));
    }
    void operator delete(void* ptr) throw()
    {
        cout<<"in overloaded delete"<<endl;
        ::operator delete(ptr); 
    }

    void* operator new[](size_t size) throw(bad_alloc)
    {
        cout<<"operatoe new[]"<<endl;
        return (::operator new[](size));
    }
    void operator delete[](void* ptr) throw()
    {
        cout<<"delete[]"<<endl;
        ::operator delete[](ptr);
    }
};
int main()
{
   Person *p1 = new Person();  //// This is fine

   Person* p2 = new Person[5];  /// This is fine

   Person* p3 = new Person[5](7) /////Want to invoke parametrized constructor..

   delete p1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you really think "this is failing" is a meaningful description of your problem and the best you can do?

Comment: compiler error coming.

Comment: If you found one of the answers helpful, you should [consider accepting one of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This rewards the answerer and also tell people looking for questions that need answers that you already have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The initializer in a `new` expression has to be of the same form as that for variable initialization (cf. [expr.new]). This means that for arrays, only three forms are allowed:

```
T * p1 = new T[N];             // default-initialization
T * p2 = new T[N]();           // value-initialization
T * p3 = new T[N] { a, b, c }; // list-initialization
```

The meaning of the initializer is the same as for variable declaration statements.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
 Person* p = new Person[5]{7, 7, 7, 7, 7};
```

?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Why not? Looks legit. (But there isn't a matching `make_unique` that emits this kind of initialization, unfortunately.)

Comment: @KerrekSB it pukes on my clang, which granted isn't the latest shiny object in the room, but it would make sense  given list-init this could work (I wonder why my clang fails?)

Comment: @WhozCraig I believe this would compile since c++11~

Comment: @owensss oh it does on ideone and coliru, but for some reason my clang 3.4 on my mac is giving me the bird. +1 btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig: See 5.3.4/(7.4)?

Comment: @KerrekSB I trust it works and is list-init supported. I just can't understand why my clang, which normally is like old-faithful for me, is thumbing its nose. I'm gonna check my proj-settings. maybe my new xcode project neglected to set C++11 support (it always seems to do that to me).

Comment: @owensss yup, C++98 was selected. sigh.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I can reproduce the problem, too. Clang works fine with fundamental type arrays, but not with this? Hmm.

Comment: @owensss ugh. kerek is right. I change to C++11 and it still pukes. egads.